# how to show green progress according to my Download Progress Percentage in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, progress-bar, custom-controls, listboxitem

All i am working on windows phone 8. 
I want to show green Progress-bar according to my download percentage into my ListBox which is filling with objects dynamically. I don't want to show moving dots which is the inbuilt Progress-bar of the windows phone 8. **So is there any control or approach for perform this OR can we have/create user-Control like green moving Progress-bar according to my download percentage in this scenario ?**

Most welcome suggesions and solutions.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show the green progress bar in windows phone 8, i have successfully done.

i made the IsDeterminate Proterty as false and bind the progresschanged event values to the Value property of my progressBar. its working superb.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="myProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" Width="900" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" CharacterSpacing="2"/>
```

It is working as i wanted. simple, easy and superb control....

Answer (score 1):

The moving dots animation is the de-facto way of indicating a process that will take an unknown amount of time. The `ProgressBar` can easily be used to show a specific step value and be of any colour you want.
e.g.

```
<ProgressBar Foreground="Green"
             Minimum="0"
             Value="50"
             Maximum="100"
             IsIndeterminate="False" />
```

Of course you'd probably bind the `Value` or set it from code behind.

Comment: i am binding the value of ProgressBar with the help of binding. i show you demo code in following line.

<ProgressBar Foreground="Green" 
             Minimum="0"
             Value="{Binding myProgressPercent}"
             Maximum="100"
             IsIndeterminate="False" />
so according to you will it work or not ?

Comment: But its not working, actually i am using this ProgressBar into my ListBox of windows phone 8 so as you know we can't access any child control of the ListBox directly through the x:Name property so unfortunately i can't assign the x:name property to the progressBar because it is useless in my case. i tried my last comment approach it is not working even it is not visibiling.